# Latex: Fig label does not function

Tags: figure, tikz

In my document, which is a book, references to figures do not function. I have already obeyed any classical methods I knew. The figures are generally produced by `tikz`, which are written by myself. I have put the label right after caption on the same line with caption, one line after caption, inside caption argument, after the `\begin{figure}`, and compiled my text more than 20 times(really more than 20 times!) and it does not work.
My machine is a linux PC (feodra 21-core).
Table of contents also does not appear. I have complied my `tex` file with two different methods which I am aware of:

```
padflatex file_name.tex
```

and

```
latex file_name.tex

dvipdf file_name.dvi
```

the both give the same result.
The caption appeaser under the figure in the pfd file.. The caption is included after `\end{tikzpicture}` and before `\end{figure}`.

Comment: I should precisely insist that nothing related to cross referencing is functioning in my document, table of contents does not appear, the references to chapters and sections does not function. and This is the first time I ma having this problem.

Comment: This should be on tex.stackexchange.com, not SO.

Comment: Also, a minimal code reproducing the problem would help a lot (I know it may be a worry if your document is big...).

Answer (score 1):

Thank you MattAllegro. I have found the root of the problem. There is no problem with latex. The problem was in a very small detail I did not pay attention and that is why I did not mention it in my question. I am posting this answer to my own question because I have learned about latex via this mistake, and i thought maybe it can be helpful to others.

In fact I did not compiled my tex file from command line. I have written a small script that does the following functions:
complies the tex file, and opens the pdf document, than transfers pdf file to a directory called pdf_files, and the other files produced during the compilation to another directory. Here is the problem. When latex or pdflatex or any compiler is compiling the tex file it looks to see if there are other documents containing any information about the currently being compiled file. It is from these preexisting files that the content of references are loaded to the final pdf file. My script (which is called clear_tex_files.sh) clears the entire directory. So any time the file is being compiled it is compiled as if it was the first compilation.

I hope this can be helpful for somebody.

Chris! If you think the question and answer are irrelevant to this page, you can delete the post entirely. From now on I will post the latex questions to its relevant page. I did know about it.